# AutoMapper Maps mix when Mapping Objects

Tags: automapper

I'm getting the following exception when using AutoMapper:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2146233088
>    Message=Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

The two models are:

- OperationSpecification
    DayofTheWeek (enum)
    OpenTime  (string)
    CloseTime (string)
- OperationalScheduling
    DayofTheWeek (enum)
    OpenTime  (string)
    CloseTime (string)

Both models have the same properties (spelled the same and in the same case)

Upon the start of the project I have a class that is called and defines all the mappings.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OperationSpecification, OperationalScheduling>();
```

I verified the AutoMapper maps by using

```
var stuff = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();
```

Putting a watch on "stuff" verifies there is a "OperationSpecification" -> "OperationalScheduling" map.

When I run the following line:

```
Mapper.Map<OperationSpecification, OperationalScheduling>(anObject);
```

I get the above error. If I look into the error details I see the following:

> Context: Trying to map OperationSpecification to DayType (an enum in the project)
>   SourceType: Name = "OperationSpecification"
>   DestinationType: Name = "DayType"

There is no mapping of this type specified in the Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps() method.

I ran Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() and confirmed the mapping.

This shifting of maps is also occurring with other mappings and objects in the project. My coworker also has the same issue. We've tried rebuilding and deleting and fetching the project from Visual Studio Online without any positive results.

Any thoughts as to what we can do to resolve this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of the Models? (or a sample models that cause the same issue to happen)

Comment: You should call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` for verification.

Comment: I checked that. I updated the post to include the properties of the class.

Comment: Looks like `anObject` is a DayType value...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Maybe there is something special about your models. Can you provide them as C# code?

Comment: by the way, what is the version of AutoMapper that you are using?

Comment: I figured out the error. I had a constructor in OperationsSpecification that took in a parameter of type DayType. I guess AutoMapper 4.0.4 didn't like that constructor in my models class.